# WSO2 REST to SOAP passing operation parameters

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

Using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1, I have configured a WSDL proxy that I want to access over REST. the proxy points to the SOAP WSDL URI and has publish WSDL turned on. This seem to work fine and I can see the service and its various operations in the WSO2 admin UI. Likewise if I go to localhost:8280/services/

The questions is how do I pass operation specific parameters when accessing over   HTTP REST?

Let's say my FooService OperationX expects a "p1" parameter, can I pass this directly when accessing localhost:8280/services/FooService/OperationX in a browser?

I tried for example localhost:8280/services/FooService/SomeOperation?p1=somevalue, but always get a validation error that the required parameter is missing:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'axis2ns15:OperationXRequest' is not complete. One of '{"somenamespace":p1}' is expected.
```

Can this be supported by a basic WSDL proxy? Or do I need to use the API?

Comment: take a look a this samples: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service#UsingRESTwithaProxyService-SOAPClientandRESTService you can send a POX request to de proxy. I think it´s better to use API in this scenario...put all the logic in sequences an just invoke this sequences from the API configuration. Also take a look a this post: http://miyurudw.blogspot.com/2013/07/wso2-esb-reading-query-parametres-from.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better option for your scenario is to use api to access over REST. Here I have created an api (I used http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments as my REST back end) which gets the query parameter(postId) which was sent in REST request (http://172.22.99.96:8290/test/comments?postId=1) and assign that value to a property called mypostId inside the api.
Then I am modifying the payload by adding the mypostId property using payload factory mediator which will match to the echo service request(I have used echo service as the SOAP backend).
Then I use enrich mediator to change my soap envelope to match the echo service request soap envelope by adding "xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"" name space. Finally I am sending my created request to echo service proxy.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/test">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/comments?postId={postId}">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Message Flow" value="--- Order GET ---"></property>
         </log>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="postId" expression="$url:postId"></property>
         </log>
         <property name="mypostId" expression="$url:postId"></property>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="GET" uri-template="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId={uri.var.postId}"></http>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <echo:echoInt xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
                  <in>$1</in>
               </echo:echoInt>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('mypostId')"></arg>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"></log>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Message Flow" value="--- After Palyload factory---"></property>
         </log>
         <property name="extarctedBody" expression="$body"></property>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="MyextarctedBody" expression="get-property('extarctedBody')"></property>
         </log>
         <log level="full"></log>
         <enrich>
            <source type="inline" clone="true">
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"></soapenv:Envelope>
            </source>
            <target type="envelope"></target>
         </enrich>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Message Flow" value="--- Order GET2 ---"></property>
         </log>
         <log level="full"></log>
         <enrich>
            <source type="property" clone="true" property="extarctedBody"></source>
            <target xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org" action="child" xpath="//soapenv:Envelope"></target>
         </enrich>
         <log level="full"></log>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8290/services/echo"></address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send></send>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Hope this may help you .

Comment: How do we set these properties to the soap service inside the insequence and pass as the proper soap request?